# Creating two Column in Word Without Text Moving to the Right on Each Paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I'm writing an assignment paper, and I would like to copy this format:

[image: https://imgur.com/OQsR8ur]

However, when I try making a new column on a selected text via: Layout > Columns > Two, the text does split into two columns, but paragraphs move to the other side instead of continuing down. I'd like to make the text fill up one side and then move to the other when there's no space.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check the paragraph formatting on the problem paragraphs.

1. Select the problem paragraphs.
2. Right click.
3. Pick Paragraph...
4. Choose the second tab at the top of the dialog box that appears.
5. On the second tab of the Format Paragraph dialog, you do not want
   the boxes for "Keep lines together" or "Keep with next" checked.